# Subrepresentation defined by a projection

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Assume H,K are Hilbert spaces and $\pi : U \to B(K)$ is a a group representation (*respectively* a group-like unitary representation) where U is a group of unitary operators in B(H) (*respectively* a group-like unitary system in B(H)).

Let $S \subset K$ be an invariant subspace of $\pi$ (i.e. ($\forall u\in U)( \forall x \in S) :  \pi(u)(x) \in S$)

Let $P : K \to K$ be the orthogonal projection on $S$.

**What does the subrepresentation of $\pi$ defined by P, denoted by $\pi | P$, mean ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It means the subrepresentation $\pi|S : U \to B(S)$.